# Prefix a string for each array values in Powershell

Tags: arrays, variables, powershell, prefix

I have a list of users that I need to grant access to a set of Windows services. It works well for a defined set of users, but I want to make the script more dynamic and pass the user and group names dynamically. I can do `foreach`, but I want to be able to prefix domain name at the beginning for each users. Example:

```
$usrs = "abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl"
```

When I do `foreach ($usr in $usrs)` it needs to prefix `"abc"` with `"AU\abc"` and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this:

```
foreach($usr in $usrs) {
    $user = "AU\$usr"
    #Continue script...
}
```

Or if you need to replace the existing array:

```
$usrs = $usrs | Foreach-Object { "AU\$_" }
#or
$usrs = foreach($usr in $usrs) { "AU\$usr" }
```

Answer (score 4):

One way to do it:

```
$usrs = "abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl" | % { "AU\"+$_ }
```

Answer (score 4):

This should help.

```
$usrs = "abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl"
foreach ($user in $usrs) {
    "AU\${user}"
}
```

Also, starting PowerShell 4.0, you can do this as well.

```
$usrs = "abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl"
$usrs.ForEach({"AU\$_"})
```

Answer (score 1):

There are so many ways to do this. Here they are, ordered from Most Performant to Slowest.

*(Performance won't matter though unless you are working with many thousands of records.)*

Starting with my favorite and most performant:

```
@("abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl") -replace '^','AU\'
```

Second most performant version (about twice as slow as the first):

```
foreach ($i in "abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl") { "AU\$i" }
```

The next form, which is about an order of magnitude slower than the first:

```
@("abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl").ForEach{ "AU\$_" }
```

Even slightly slower than the ForEach method since it utilizes the pipeline:

```
"abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl" | % { "AU\$_" }
```

Even though this version (@Micky contributed) is over a magnitude slower than the first option I listed above, I think it is the easiest to read for most PowerShell users. Very clean and the pipeline with ForEach-Object every PowerShell user is almost sure to immediately recognize and understand. So it is my second favorite on this list.

Last but not least, and I think is also pretty easy to read, calling the Insert() method of each string. Note that this is at least two orders of magnitude slower than the first:

```
"abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl" | % Insert 0, 'AU\'
```

or in an older version of PowerShell you can use:

```
"abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl" | % Insert -ArgumentList @(0, 'AU\')
```

or another form of the same:

```
"abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl" | % { $_.Insert(0, 'AU\') }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing this in a nested loop, the inner loop can't access any variables from the outer loop. Here's an alternative that will work in both contexts:

```
$usrs = @("abc", "def", "ghi") 
$prefixValue = 'AU\'
$usrs | ForEach-Object -Member Insert -ArgumentList @(0, $prefixValue)
```